# Python: How to change a keyboard layout in the keylogger?

Tags: python, keyboard, keylogger, pynput

I am doing keylogger that prints the key I pressed. And I have a problem. When I change my keyboard layout the layout does not change. Please help me.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def on_press(key):
    print('{0} pressed'.format(
        key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} release'.format(
        key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Please, be more specific. Where do you change your layout? And where do you expect it to change?

Comment: I guess the idea is to be able to register characters appropriate for a given language, like for example for Polish: ś ą ć.